# How to count consecutive duplicates and keep one in a column and combine others values in a second column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Scala and I'm facing a blockage, your help would be useful.

I've a log file already parsed and loaded as a dataframe under Scala:

```
+-------------------+---------------+
|     Breakdown_Type|Breakdown_Level|
+-------------------+---------------+
|           standard|             19|
|           standard|             12|
|           standard|             14|
|           standard|             19|
|            traffic|             14|
|         traffic_hd|             12|
|        standard_hd|             13|
|         traffic_hd|             12|
|           standard|             14|
|        standard_hd|             14|
|            traffic|             14|
|            traffic|             17|
|           standard|             19|
|           standard|             17|
|public_transport_hd|             15|
|           standard|             18|
|           standard|             18|
|           standard|             19|
|           standard|             14|
|        standard_hd|             18|
+-------------------+---------------+
```

What I want is:

```
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|     Breakdown_Type|Breakdown_Level|          count|
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|           standard|    19,12,14,19|              4|
|            traffic|             14|              1|
|         traffic_hd|             12|              1|
|        standard_hd|             13|              1|
|         traffic_hd|             12|              1|
|           standard|             14|              1|
|        standard_hd|             14|              1|
|            traffic|          14,17|              2|
|            .......|             ..|             ..|  
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I've tested with

```
df.groupBy($"Breakdown_Type")
  .agg(collect_set($"Breakdown_Level") as "Breakdown_Level")
  .orderBy($"Breakdown_Type".asc)
  .show()
```

This grouped all the duplicates which isn't what I want.

```
+-------------------+--------------------+
|     Breakdown_Type|     Breakdown_Level|
+-------------------+--------------------+
|public_transport_hd|                [15]|
|           standard|[12, 19, 17, 18, 14]|
|        standard_hd|        [13, 18, 14]|
|            traffic|            [17, 14]|
|         traffic_hd|                [12]|
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

I added a monotonicallyIncreasingId as column"id" in order to keep the original order in case of groupBy, I used a Window also but the result isn't as expected

````
val xxx  =df_exo2.withColumn("Count",count("Breakdown_Type")
             .over(Window.partitionBy("Breakdown_Type").orderBy(asc("id"))))
             .withColumn("Breakdown_Levels",collect_list("Breakdown_Level")
             .over(Window.partitionBy("Breakdown_Type").orderBy(asc("id"))))
             .sort("id")

xxx.show()```
````

```
+---+-------------------+---------------+-----+--------------------+
| id|     Breakdown_Type|Breakdown_Level|Count|    Breakdown_Levels|
+---+-------------------+---------------+-----+--------------------+
|  0|           standard|             19|    1|                [19]|
|  1|           standard|             12|    2|            [19, 12]|
|  2|           standard|             14|    3|        [19, 12, 14]|
|  3|           standard|             19|    4|    [19, 12, 14, 19]|
|  4|            traffic|             14|    1|                [14]|
|  5|         traffic_hd|             12|    1|                [12]|
|  6|        standard_hd|             13|    1|                [13]|
|  7|         traffic_hd|             12|    2|            [12, 12]|
|  8|           standard|             14|    5|[19, 12, 14, 19, 14]|
|  9|        standard_hd|             14|    2|            [13, 14]|
| 10|            traffic|             14|    2|            [14, 14]|
| 11|            traffic|             17|    3|        [14, 14, 17]|
| 12|           standard|             19|    6|[19, 12, 14, 19, ...|
| 13|           standard|             17|    7|[19, 12, 14, 19, ...|
| 14|public_transport_hd|             15|    1|                [15]|
| 15|           standard|             18|    8|[19, 12, 14, 19, ...|
| 16|           standard|             18|    9|[19, 12, 14, 19, ...|
| 17|           standard|             19|   10|[19, 12, 14, 19, ...|
| 18|           standard|             14|   11|[19, 12, 14, 19, ...|
| 19|        standard_hd|             18|    3|        [13, 14, 18]|
+---+-------------------+---------------+-----+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val globalWindow = Window.orderBy("id")
val upToThisRowWindow = globalWindow.rowsBetween(-Long.MaxValue - 1, 0)

val finalDF = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
    .withColumn("groups", sum(when(lag("Breakdown_Type", 1).over(globalWindow) =!= col("Breakdown_Type"), 1).otherwise(0)).over(upToThisRowWindow) + 1)

finalDF.groupBy("groups", "Breakdown_Type").agg(collect_list("Breakdown_Level"))
    .withColumnRenamed("collect_list(Breakdown_Level)", "Breakdown_Level")
    .withColumn("count", size(col("Breakdown_Level"))).drop("groups")
    .show
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+----------------+-----+
|     Breakdown_Type| Breakdown_Level|count|
+-------------------+----------------+-----+
|           standard|[19, 12, 14, 19]|    4|
|            traffic|            [14]|    1|
|         traffic_hd|            [12]|    1|
|        standard_hd|            [13]|    1|
|         traffic_hd|            [12]|    1|
|           standard|            [14]|    1|
|        standard_hd|            [14]|    1|
|            traffic|        [14, 17]|    2|
|           standard|        [19, 17]|    2|
|public_transport_hd|            [15]|    1|
|           standard|[18, 18, 19, 14]|    4|
|        standard_hd|            [18]|    1|
+-------------------+----------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

I consider this dataframe

```
val df = Seq(("standard", 10),("standard", 12),("standard", 15),("traffic", 5),("traffic", 8),("standard", 19),("standard", 10),("traffic", 25),("stand                           ard", 21),("traffic", 34)).toDF("Breakdown_Type", "Breakdown_Level")
df.show(false)
+--------------+---------------+
|Breakdown_Type|Breakdown_Level|
+--------------+---------------+
|standard      |10             |
|standard      |12             |
|standard      |15             |
|traffic       |5              |
|traffic       |8              |
|standard      |19             |
|standard      |10             |
|traffic       |25             |
|standard      |21             |
|traffic       |34             |
+--------------+---------------+
```

Start by adding an index column

```
val indexDF = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Then create your Window partitioned by index column,
and create lag column (previous row) so you can compare each row with previous one

```
val win = Window.orderBy("id")
val lagCol = lag(col("Breakdown_Type"), 1).over(win)
val lagdf = indexDF.withColumn("lag", lagCol)
lagdf.show(false)
+--------------+---------------+---+--------+
|Breakdown_Type|Breakdown_Level|id |lag     |
+--------------+---------------+---+--------+
|standard      |10             |0  |null    |
|standard      |12             |1  |standard|
|standard      |15             |2  |standard|
|traffic       |5              |3  |standard|
|traffic       |8              |4  |traffic |
|standard      |19             |5  |traffic |
|standard      |10             |6  |standard|
|traffic       |25             |7  |standard|
|standard      |21             |8  |traffic |
|traffic       |34             |9  |standard|
+--------------+---------------+---+--------+
```

Then, the most important step, compare each row with the previous one, if they are equal, return 0, otherwise return 1

```
val compareDF = lagdf.withColumn("eq", when(col("Breakdown_Type") === col("lag"), 0).otherwise(1))
compareDF.show(false)
+--------------+---------------+---+--------+---+
|Breakdown_Type|Breakdown_Level|id |lag     |eq |
+--------------+---------------+---+--------+---+
|standard      |10             |0  |null    |1  |
|standard      |12             |1  |standard|0  |
|standard      |15             |2  |standard|0  |
|traffic       |5              |3  |standard|1  |
|traffic       |8              |4  |traffic |0  |
|standard      |19             |5  |traffic |1  |
|standard      |10             |6  |standard|0  |
|traffic       |25             |7  |standard|1  |
|standard      |21             |8  |traffic |1  |
|traffic       |34             |9  |standard|1  |
+--------------+---------------+---+--------+---+
```

Then, you need to apply cumulative sum, which will allow you to have groups of consecutive same values

```
val cumSumDF = compareDF.withColumn("cum", sum(col("eq")).over(bkWin.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)))
cumSumDF.show(false)
+--------------+---------------+---+--------+---+---+
|Breakdown_Type|Breakdown_Level|id |lag     |eq |cum|
+--------------+---------------+---+--------+---+---+
|standard      |10             |0  |null    |1  |1  |
|standard      |12             |1  |standard|0  |1  |
|standard      |15             |2  |standard|0  |1  |
|traffic       |5              |3  |standard|1  |2  |
|traffic       |8              |4  |traffic |0  |2  |
|standard      |19             |5  |traffic |1  |3  |
|standard      |10             |6  |standard|0  |3  |
|traffic       |25             |7  |standard|1  |4  |
|standard      |21             |8  |traffic |1  |5  |
|traffic       |34             |9  |standard|1  |6  |
+--------------+---------------+---+--------+---+---+
```

Final step, groupBy your new column (cum), and create a list

```
val finalDF = cumSumDF.groupBy("cum" ,"Breakdown_Type").agg(collect_list("Breakdown_Level"))
finalDF.show(false)
+---+--------------+-----------------------------+
|cum|Breakdown_Type|collect_list(Breakdown_Level)|
+---+--------------+-----------------------------+
|1  |standard      |[10, 12, 15]                 |
|2  |traffic       |[5, 8]                       |
|3  |standard      |[19, 10]                     |
|4  |traffic       |[25]                         |
|5  |standard      |[21]                         |
|6  |traffic       |[34]                         |
+---+--------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: I've tested both answers, and I really appreciated the step by step explanation. this worked for me.